# Rigour behind showing that $f(x) = c$ where $c$ is a constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Rigour behind showing that $f(x) = c$ where $c$ is a constant.

When being taught that a constant function is continuous usually professors just gloss over that the $\delta$ could be any value. So it got me thinking of how to demonstrate it completely rigorously.

So by definition a function is continuous at a point $a$ if:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \ \exists \ \delta > 0 \ s.t \ if\ |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow  |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

Let $f(x) = c$, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

So to show this explicitly I would have to "extract" a $|x-a|$ out of my expression and then obtain a $\delta$ by this relationship. I'm curious if I "extracted" the $|x-a|$ in the correct fashion:

$$|c-c| \leq |ac - xc + xc -ac| \leq |x-a||c-c| < \delta |c-c| = \delta  \bullet 0 < \epsilon$$

The step in this inequality that is troubling me is whether I can get away with the $|c-c| \leq |ac-ac|$ it feels as if that shouldn't be an issue, but I'm not 100% sure.  Thoughts?

Comment: Note that both $|c-c|$ and $|ac-ac|$ are equal to zero, so your inequality is in fact an equality.

Comment: There is no need to "extract" anything.  $|f(x) - f(a)| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Comment: That was where my initial idea did come from and just by the properties of fields I figured that the difference between two objects will not change if the scalar was multiplied on each object

Comment: @RobertIsrael but what if I'm trying to "show that my $\delta$ works? This is why I ask the question.

Comment: Any $\delta > 0$ works because $0 < \epsilon$.

Comment: There's nothing to show, it's not dependent of $\delta$. You can choose any $\delta$ and there'll be nothing different about the proof, because $|f(x)-f(a)|=0<\varepsilon$, *always*.

Comment: @YuvalGat I don't deny that fact, what I was getting at is showing that  the inequality does not depend on $\delta$

Comment: $|f(x)-f(a)|=|c-c|=0$ regardless of your choice of $\delta$. Is this what you meant? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to get at if that's not it...

Comment: I get where you guys are coming from. I figured it out......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formal proof could be written in the following way, to show that $f(x) = c$ is continuous at some $a \in \mathbb{R}$:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $\delta = 1$; then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(a)| = |c-c| = 0 < \epsilon$.
>
> Hence $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. So $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Remark, of course, that the choice of $\delta>0$ was completely arbitrary, since it had no impact on the conclusion.